# Degree of dissociation of weak electrolyte at infinite dilution

Tags: physical-chemistry, ionic-compounds

Why the degree of dissociation of weak electrolyte is 1 at infinite dilution and how do we get the result? Like I know that at infinite dilution the concentration of solution is 0 but what does that have to do with degree of dissociation, secondly in oswald's law of dilution we already assume that dissociation is almost negligible so we can't obtain the result from that also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to explain this. In words, the entropic gain with dissociation overwhelms any attraction between counterions as the electrolyte is diluted.

Mathematically: for a m:n electrolyte undergoing dissociation according to the reaction

$$\ce{A_mB_n -> mA^{\nu_A -} + nB^{\nu_B +}}$$

if the initial concentration of electrolyte $\ce{A_mB_n}$ is $c_{T}$, define the degree of dissociation as

$$\alpha = \frac{c_{AB}}{c_{T}}$$

where $c_{AB}$ is the concentration of *dissociated* $\ce{A_mB_n}$. Assuming ideality and unit molarity as standard concentration, the equation for the equilibrium constant can be written as $$K=\frac{c_A^m c_B^n}{c_{AB}}$$ and solved in terms of the degree of dissociation. For a 1:1 electrolyte this leads to

$$\alpha = \frac{\beta}{2}\left[\left(1 + \frac{4}{\beta} \right)^{1/2} -1\right] \tag{1}$$

where $\beta = K/c_T$. As $c_T \rightarrow 0$ it follows from this last expression that $\alpha  \rightarrow 1$ #QED

PS The following equation (from Wikipedia's page on [Ostwald's law of dilution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_dilution)) $$\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{K}{c_T}} \tag{2}$$ does not hold over the entire concentration range $c_T$. It can be obtained from Eq. (1) by assuming $K<<1$ and therefore $\beta<<1$. For increasingly dilute solution Eq. (2) fails and  $\alpha  \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Not always does $\alpha\to 1$.  Other answers give counterexamples.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Good point, I didn't even think about water autodissociation since I was considering simple electrolytes and not about other interfering equilibria.

Answer (score 3):

For infinite dilution, water acts as a buffer with $\mathrm{pH}=7$.

Therefore, $\alpha=f(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a})$.

For $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=9$ is $\alpha=\frac{1}{101}\overset{cca}=0.01$.

For $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=8$ is $\alpha=\frac1{11}$.

For $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=7$ is $\alpha=0.5$, as only a half of the acid is dissociated.

For $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=6$ is $\alpha=\frac{10}{11}$.

For $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}=5$ is $\alpha=\frac{100}{101}\overset{cca}=0.99$.

The same applies for conjugate acids of respective weak bases.

Answer (score 3):

If the weak electrolyte is a weak *acid*, we have to reckon with the autoionization of water.  With the autoionization, the solvated ions formed from the acid do not reach infinite dilution and therefore the dissociation is limited to below 100%.

Let's look at acetic acid, for which (if I remember and can type correctly) $K_a=1.8×10^{-5}$.  Thereby*

$\dfrac{[\ce{H^+}][\ce{C2H3O2^-}]}{[\ce{HC2H3O2}]}=1.8×10^{-5}$

*Ion formulas omit water of solvation.

In the limiting case of infinite dilution of the acid we will have $[\ce{H^+}]\to10^{-7}$ forcing

$\dfrac{[\ce{C2H3O2^-}]}{[\ce{HC2H3O2}]}\to180$

and since the amount of acetate ion equals the amount of dissociated acetic acid molecules the degree of dissociation is limited to

$\dfrac{[\ce{C2H3O2^-}]}{[\ce{C2H3O2^-}]+[\ce{HC2H3O2}]}\to\dfrac{180}{181}=99.4\text{ per cent}$

The general formula for the dissociation limit would be

$\dfrac{K_a}{K_a + 10^{-7}}$

In the case of acetic acid the autoionization places very little limitation on the dissociation because the acid is comparatively strong versus the maximum autoionization from the water.  If we had chosen a weaker acid with $K_a<10^{-7}$ then the (relative) flooding of solvated hydrogen ions from autoionization would prevent the acid from ever reaching majority dissociation.  For example, $\ce{HCN}$ in the absence of anything that complexes cyanide ions would remain predominantly molecular in water solution, no matter how much it's diluted.